# Given the local coordinates of a parented object, how do I get its global coordinates using the Python API?

Tags: python, coordinates

Here is my setup:

- I have the default cube
- I make a sphere and move it y+4 (now at 0,4,0)
- I parent the sphere (child) to the cube (parent)
- the sphere location is [0,4,0] in local coordinates. It's the same for global coordinates. (This is a simplified example.)

I want to programmatically get the sphere's coordinates in the global space.

Scouring the web, I have found the following general formula for getting global coordinates from local ones:

```
sphere.matrix_world * sphere.location
```

In the above example, if I plug that into the python console, it produces [0,8,0]. Why 8? It should be 4, no? Is this not the correct formula? If I make the example more complex (by rotating the cube, for example) I still get this 'doubling' effect. [0,3,0] becomes [0,6,0]. What is the correct python expression to get the correct *global* coordinates of the parented sphere?

Answer (score 7):

The formula is

```
default_cube.matrix_world * sphere.matrix_basis
```

You can directly get the global coordinates (including constraints) of the sphere from

```
sphere.matrix_world.translation
```

See [Object.matrix_basis](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_2/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=matrix_basis#bpy.types.Object.matrix_basis), [mathutils.Matrix](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_2/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.matrix#mathutils.Matrix)

Comment: There's also a more or less equal alternative to `Object.matrix_world.translation`: [to_translation()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_2/mathutils.html?highlight=to_translation#mathutils.Matrix.to_translation). In contrast to `translation`, there's always a copy made and modifications to the Vector object won't affect the original matrix.

Comment: i have a sphere (with follow path constraints) parented to empty. when i run `print(sphere.matrix_world.translation)` i don't get the correct world space coordinates. But when i remove the constraint then it is correct. you claimed it should work with constraints. Do you know what changed in blender 3.1?

Comment: ah i found the reason [here in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27668/142292) and need to call `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` and then the value of `print(sphere.matrix_world.translation)` is correct.