# Incorrect matrix_world after transformation

Tags: python, objects, transforms

This script changes the active object's location, it could also change the rotation or scale, it also prints the object's world matrix before and after changing the location.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
print(obj.matrix_world)
obj.location = 1, 2, 3
print(obj.matrix_world)
```

The output shows the same matrix as before and after the translation:

```
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

However accessing the matrix from the python console, `bpy.context.object.matrix_world`, shows the correct world matrix with the translation (the last column):

```
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Therefore, what is the correct way to access the modified matrix values after changing an object's 
*location*, *rotation*, or *scale*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stackoverflow has a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840418/3220986) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13899286/3220986) on the same issue. The problem is blender is not recalculate the matrix immediately after modifying the transformation.

As [mgibsonbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520779/mgibsonbr) notes, to have the correct values, add `scene.update()` after the changes to recalculate the matrix.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
print(obj.matrix_world)
obj.location = 1, 2, 3
bpy.context.scene.update()
print(obj.matrix_world)
```

Which now correctly prints:

```
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 2.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 3.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

Comment: what is the equivalent of `bpy.context.scene.update()` in blender 3.1? *EDIT* ahhh found it `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`

Answer (score 15):

Note for those using blender 2.8x: `scene.update()` has been removed as of 2.80. Use `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` instead, as per [this post](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API#Scene_update).

Comment: If in your script the object is moving between frames, you can simply use: `scene.frame_set(scene.frame_current)` this will update the matrix_world of the objects