# Updating an object's location via the python API (3.1+)

Tags: python, modifiers, objects, transforms, origin

I have been playing around with Blender's python API, this is a function I wrote to update an object's location:

```
def apply_translation_point(object: bpy.types.Object, location: Vector, modifier_log: ModifierLog, log=True, return_vector=False):
    """
    Translate a given object's origin to a specified location, provided point
    must be in world coordinates
    """
    origin = object.location.copy()
    translation_vector = location - origin
    object.location += translation_vector
    print('Updated location: ', object.location) # this prints the correct object location

    if log: # ignore this this is a custom class object I use to log operations to reconstruct my scenes outside blender
        modifier_log.log_translation(translation_vector)
        
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    object.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=False, scale=False)
    print('Location After applying transform: ', object.location) # this prints (0,0,0)
    
    if return_vector:
        return translation_vector
```

This is the output on the blender console:
[image]

Can someone please break down what is happening here in the context of how the Blender Python API is structured? The object does get translated to the correct position but when I try to fetch the `object.location` attribute it is returned as the default value (as specified in the documentation), do I need to update anything else here (I did try calling the `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27667/incorrect-matrix-world-after-transformation) after updating the object location, but that didn't work)?

Comment: With `bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True)`, you are [Applying](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) the location transfomation which basically is, quoting from documentation *"Applying transform values essentially resets the values of object’s location (or rotation or scale), while visually keeping the object data in-place. The object origin point is moved to the global origin, (or the rotation is cleared or scale values are set to 1)."*.

Comment: Thanks! I see... so the `bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()` essentially changes the default state of an object, i.e. resets all values to default but it still preserves the object "state" reached after applying all the modifiers to the object. I was learning Blender through blogs/tutorials and it was common practice and was recommended to "apply" the transforms after using modifiers on the objects.

Comment: well it depends what you are trying to accomplish. i don't usually need to apply transforms. just sometimes when i scale the object in object mode. then i apply the scale. or something the rotation.

Comment: Ususally applying translation doesn't change much because the tutorials don't tell you to move the object, ie when you mirror model a character or a car you want it to always stay at the origin point for ease of use. Applying the translation effectively moves the vertices in edit mode and zeroes out the translation component of the transform. You should almost always want the scale component to be applied (1,1,1) though, unless you specifically want your model to not be with a uniform scale